# How to get a non-random value from a randomly selected value?

Tags: php, arrays, random, variable-assignment

I am trying to select a non-random value for a random selected value.

- the first column represents the sale number (1-30)
- the second column shows the item which must be selected at random
- the third column shows the corresponding price for said item

How can I achieve this given that the item is selected at random?

I had thought of using a switch statement but that this might get messy.

```
$items = array( ‘clock’ , ‘kettle’ , ‘mug’ , ‘toaster’ , ‘CD’);
$prices = array( '£30', '£19', '£5' , '£14' , '£7');

for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $sales[$i][0] = $i + 1; //Starts at 1 and increments
    $sales[$i][1] =  $items[rand(0,4)]; //Item chosen at random
    $sales[$i][2] = //Should be the corresponding price for the above item.
}
```

Comment: `$random = rand(0,4); $sales[$o][1] = $items[$random]; $sales[$i][2] = $items[$random];` ?!

Comment: Show your `$sales` array or wherever your pricing information is stored.  Without that we have no idea how to help you. Right now it is not clear how you relate the items in `$items` to any sales pricing.

Comment: .. or `array_rand()`

Comment: @MikeBrant apologies, edited.
Would putting '$random = rand(0,4);' inside the loop then using 
$items[$random];
$prices[$random]; 
work?

Comment: Store the result of `rand(0,4)` in a variable and use it to access the elements of each array.

Comment: Why not store items and prices in a single, multi-dimensional array? `$data = array (array('item' => 'clock', 'price' => 30), array('item' => 'kettle', 'price' => 19), ...)`?

Comment: I agree with approach suggested by @Barmar  That makes really clear as the relation between items and price.

Answer (score 3):

```
$items = array( ‘clock’ , ‘kettle’ , ‘mug’ , ‘toaster’ , ‘CD’);
$prices = array( '£30', '£19', '£5' , '£14' , '£7');

for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $sales[$i][0] = $i + 1; //Starts at 1 and increments
    $sales[$i][1] =  $items[rand(0,4)]; //Item chosen at random
    $sales[$i][2] = //Should be the corresponding price for the above item
}
```

Watch and learn:

```
$items = array( ‘clock’ , ‘kettle’ , ‘mug’ , ‘toaster’ , ‘CD’);
$prices = array( '£30', '£19', '£5' , '£14' , '£7');

for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $random = rand(0,4);

    $sales[$i][0] = $i + 1; //Starts at 1 and increments
    $sales[$i][1] = $items[$random]; //Item chosen at random
    $sales[$i][2] = $prices[$random];
}
```